# Using Azure ADB2C and MSAL, is it possible to refresh the bearer token without re-entering the password?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, bearer-token

### Current situation

I have an ADB2C server with these settings:

- A custom User Attribute `InstancesAvailable` was created
- This user attribute is set to be returned as an Application claims in in my "Sign up and sign in (Recommended)" user flow
- An API connector is defined to be executed "Before including application claims in token (preview)" in the user flow
- My API endpoint defined to be called from the API connector is returning an `extension_InstancesAvailable` property, to be added as a claims in the bearer token produced by the Identity server

All of that is working, the typical use case is:

1. A user signs in to my React web app using MSAL and the above user flow defined in ADB2C
2. During the sign-in process, my API endpoint is thus called for constructing and returning the custom `extension_InstancesAvailable` claims value to be added by the Identity server
3. Once the user gets signed into my application, his bearer token correctly includes the `extension_InstancesAvailable` claims value

### Question

I am thinking forward: There will be an action available in my web application to "add a new instance". Since the list of available instances is forged into the bearer token during the sign-in, is there a way to "regenerate" the bearer token of a user, without having to sign-out/sign-in or even re-enter password?

Ideally, I would like to regenerate the bearer token after a specific action is done inside my web app, so the `extension_InstancesAvailable` contains the correct list, including the one just created by the user.

Comment: If you are using MSAL then there is no need to refresh the token as MSAL also refreshes the token when the token is getting close to expire because the token cache contains a refresh token. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74934320/error-bearer-error-invalid-token-validate-token-with-msal/74960945#74960945

Comment: @Rukmini is it possible to force refresh the bearer token before expiration? If yes, what javascript code would achieve that?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/5623

Answer (score 0):

`MSAL.js` does not use `refresh tokens` in the browser, but  `acquireTokenSilent` method to request a [new access token](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/token-lifetimes.md) using a [`hidden iframe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111753/is-it-possible-to-use-msal-js-to-get-refresh-token.). It invokes the same user flow used to sign in, & call API connector to get the updated value of the `extension_InstancesAvailable` claim. This approach fails if there are network issues, browser restrictions, or user interaction

The GitHub link below is a  different scenario, where the user wants to refresh the `ID token`, not  `access token`. Former can be refreshed by passing the client ID as the only scope in the `acquireTokenSilent` method. However, this will not affect the value of the `extension_InstancesAvailable` claim, which is only relevant for the access token.

```js
// Create an instance of MSAL
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "your-client-id",
    authority: "your-authority",
    redirectUri: "your-redirect-uri"
  }
};
const msalInstance = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

// Define the scopes and account for the token request
const tokenRequest = {
  scopes: ["your-scopes"], // use [msalConfig.auth.clientId] to refresh ID token
  account: msalInstance.getAccount()
};

// Call acquireTokenSilent to get a new token
msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
  .then(response => {
    // Handle the response
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle the error
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Other references

[msal.js - MSAL-browser refresh token - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890181/msal-browser-refresh-token).

[MSAL-browser refresh token - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/339692/msal-browser-refresh-token).

[Token Lifetimes, Expiration, and Renewal - GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/token-lifetimes.md).

[Is it possible to use MSAL.js to get refresh token? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111753/is-it-possible-to-use-msal-js-to-get-refresh-token).

[Correct way to Refresh a token from MSAL before an AJAX call? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67996243/correct-way-to-refresh-a-token-from-msal-before-an-ajax-call).

[GitHub - Token Lifetimes, Expiration, and Renewal (Raw)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/token-lifetimes.md?raw=true).

[Microsoft Docs - Configurable Token Lifetimes](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

[GitHub - MSAL for JavaScript](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js).